# chinese fonts doesn't work on github pages even with google api and adobe fonts

Tags: html, css, fonts

I want to add a chinese font to my website.

I used a font from fonts.google with both @import and , https:// and http://.

I then turned to adobe fonts (with education subscription from school) and copied their  tag.

I added .ttf, .woff, .woff2 files of downloaded fonts

None of these worked.

What's more stressing is that the same web-fonts I connected through their links worked on my local .html file but not on my github pages website.

If anyone could help me with a working, reliable method to add chinese fonts to github pages, please.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this yet:

https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/typography/font-list/microsoft-yahei

I have read that this works on GitHub.

Comment: thanks! it seems that certain ttf files work.

Comment: np, glad it worked :)